# Check if null and empty string in Laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

in my view I have to output separately the one that is `null` and the one that is `empty string`

so i have this:

```
@if( $str->a == null)
... // do somethin
@endif

@if( $str->a == '')
... // do somethin
@endif
```

the problem is they the same result.

Thanks

Comment: Why do they need seperate outputs? They very nearly basically mean the same thing. In what usecase would it matter if its one or the other for your application? This sounds like an **[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/360627)** to me.

Comment: try changing `==` to `===`

Comment: actually, it should only shows the ones that is null and not the one that is empty.

Comment: Just use 1 `if` statement, and use `if(empty($str->a)` - this will check all similar cases, and make sure the value is valid at all. Read about `empty` on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 30):

In the comments you've said you only want to check if it is `null`. So, use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php):

```
@if (is_null($str->a))
    // do somethin
@endif
```

Answer (score 27):

```
@if( !empty($str->a))
... // do somethin
@endif
```

This are consider for empty

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
@isset($str->a)
    // $str->a is defined and is not null...
@endisset

@empty($str->a)
    // $str->a is "empty"...
@endempty
```

[If Statements Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#if-statements)

Comment: Using Laravel 8 - this is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

`$str->a` can't be null and `''` at the same time. Have you tried `@elseif`?

```
@if( is_null($str->a))
... // do somethin
@elseif( $str->a == '')
... // do somethin
@endif
```

> actually, it should only shows the ones that is null and not the one that is empty.

It sounds like you want to check if `$str->a` is a valid string or not. As suggested in comments by @GrumpyCrouton you can use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

```
@if( empty($str->a))
... // do somethin
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also PHP's [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function, which Laravel uses under the hood in its `@isset` Blade helper, making it a natural option if you're not in a Blade template but want to do something similar.